# Visual Studio Code error: "Running as administrator is not supported"

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

For some reason after an update, VS Code is not allowing me to run as administrator.
For the work I do, it is not an option to not run as admin.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks related to enabling Electron's sandbox by default. The work-around is disabling it.

Edit your settings.json file, which can be found in `C:\users\<userid>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User` to include this line:

```
"window.experimental.useSandbox": false
```

Comment: did not work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling the chromium sandbox: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_disable-chromium-sandbox.

To disable it for a single VS Code window, start that window from the commandline with the `--disable-chromium-sandbox` flag, like `code --disable-chromium-sandbox`. Or alternatively, `code --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox`.

If you want to have that flag always be used automatically, you can put it in VS Code's `argv.json` file, which you can open by using the `Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), and then put `"disable-chromium-sandbox": true` in it and restart VS Code.