# Unable to Write File in Visual studio on MAC, using Cypress tool

Tags: visual-studio-code, cypress

I'm getting below error while creating a new file in Visual studio code on MAC OS, using cypress tool
Unable to write file '/Users/passivelogic/Documents/CypressProject/cypress/e2e/test2.cy.js' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/passivelogic/Documents/CypressProject/cypress/e2e/test2.cy.js')
Could you please help me out to overcome this?
NOT: Visual Studio code is already put up in Applications folder .

I tried giving administrator privileges to Visual studio code but it dint work.

Comment: potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76205701/11107541